# find last empty string in x value and make new line

Tags: php, arrays, string, foreach, split

I have a string and I want to make new line on a last empty space of a 50 long string.

```
<?php
$str = "the condition that distinguishes animals and plants from inorganic matter, including the capacity for growth, reproduction, functional activity, and continual change preceding death.";

$a = str_split($str, 50);

foreach ($a as $value) {
    $lastspace = strrpos($value, " ");
    echo chunk_split($value, $lastspace, "<br>");
}
?>
```

**Expected result:**

the condition that distinguishes animals and
plants from inorganic matter, including the
capacity for growth, reproduction, functional
activity, and continual change preceding death.

Comment: maybe you could use this regex for replace `(\s)\w*$`

Comment: show me an example / answer so I can mark it as correct one.

Comment: What would the result be given your string?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I added expected result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not always perfect (for better implementations just search `wordwrap`) but this normally works well:

```
echo wordwrap($str, 50, '<br>');
```